# How to sniff Bluetooth Input/Output of my laptop

Tags: bluetooth, packet-sniffers, sniffing, sniffer

I have a device (some kind of lab measurement device) that connects to a PC with Bluetooth, and through its application only. Now I want to re-create this app for myself, to add some changes, but to do so I need to know what commands the current app sends to the device to start or stop the testing process and what the device sends back to the app as the measured data. how can I sneak in between the device, the PC's Bluetooth, and the application to get this info? I rather the solution not require an exatuic piece of hardware please (as I saw in other related questions).

I tried to connect to the device with my phone to use a Bluetooth serial app to read the commands. that was when I realized that the Windows app also sends some commands to the device as well (obviously) and without those commands, the device won't do anything. I can try to hardware hack the device as I have access to its PCB and everything, but I'm very limited in time, so I thought there might be an easier software kind of way to do the same thing. I have seen videos about ble sniffing with an NRF52810, but I don't know if that's what I need, so I thought I should ask here before purchasing anything.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/testing-btp-tools-btvs